# DataBinding not working in module

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm using data binding within my app. I have an application module and the data binding is working successfully.

However, I also have a 'home-module' I'm trying to use the same techniques, but the data binding is erroring in the xml with the following:

> Error:(63, 34) No resource type specified (at 'onClick' with value
>   '@{viewModel::onButtonClicked}').

I've found [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177621) which suggests this was an issue but it's been fixed.

I can't see any issues with the code, I think the problem is because it's in the library module.

Is there anything I can do to get this working?

**home-module**

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.flowmellow.projectx.home.ui.viewmodel.HomeViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.flowmellow.projectx.home.ui.viewmodel.HomeActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.flowmellow.projectx.home.ui.viewmodel.HomeActivity">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/activity_home_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/activity_home_title"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_home_button"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/activity_home_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/activity_home_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:onClick="@{viewModel::onButtonClicked}"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HomeViewModel mHomeViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        final CustomSensorManager customSensorManager = new CustomSensorManager(sensorManager);
        mHomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(customSensorManager);

        setBindingContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    private void setBindingContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        ActivityHomeBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutResID);
        binding.setViewModel(mHomeViewModel);
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel

```
public class HomeViewModel {

    private CustomSensorManager mSensorManager;

    public HomeViewModel(@NonNull CustomSensorManager sensorManager) {
        mSensorManager = sensorManager;
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
        mSensorManager.scan(true);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

Update:

Could be a bug. [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195339)

**My problem:**

[image]

The engine module has no UI, so the dependency was missed, makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Do you have data binding enabled in both the library and the application modules?

Comment: Yes, enabled in the application module

Comment: I just tested this and it works. I suspect that you don't have data binding enabled in the library module also.

Comment: 100% I did have DataBinding enabled in both application and the library module. Thank for testing. But If it's working for you I must have done something wrong... I'll just have to try again. Thanks for spending the time.

Comment: FYI The build.gradle from the library module was copied into the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Say you have a multilevel module hierarchy like this in your app:

[image: Multilevel module hierarchy in Android]

In order for databinding to work module A, you have to make sure you enable databinding in **the whole hierarchy** from the root module into module A.

That means you have to add:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

To the modules:

- app module
- module A
- module B

It is important to remember that you do **have** to also enable databinding in `module B`, so all paths are covered.

Comment: Yes! This was my problem, I had another module dependant on home-module. Working fine now thank you.

Comment: Is this still required? I face a problem where I have an android module whose 3rd child dependency uses databinding. When I add databinding to app gradle as well, I get R8: Program type already present exception which does not happen if I remove it from the app module.

Comment: Is this requirement mentioned in android official doc?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue same and got some information to solved it.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#build_environment

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34873245)